# Как сделать Alert по таймингу ? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if, alert

Task: Нажимаем на кнопку , начинается отсчет времени. По истечению 5 , 10 , 15 секунд , должно появиться 3 Алерта.  Не выходит сделать Алерт по таймингу. Проблема заключается именно в тайминге , с алертом проблем нет. Заранее большое спасибо за помощь! Код:

```
import UIKit

public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
         let firstReminder = Property(message: " ", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0 , seconds: 5)

         let secondReminder = Property(message: "Good morning", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0 , seconds: 10)
         
         let thirdReminder = Property(message: "Hi", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0 , seconds: 15)
    
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You are playing too much", message: "What about break", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    
    var time = 0
    
    //timer
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        if firstReminder.seconds == 5 {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: {
            (action) in
            print("OK")
        }))
        
        self.present(alert, animated:true)
        
       print("Success")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        //timer.invalidate()
        time = 0
        lbl.text = ("0")
    }
    
    @objc func action()
    {
        time += 1
        lbl.text = String(time)
    
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
   public override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
  >      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
        }

>public class Property {
    var message: String , days = 0 , hours = 1 , seconds = 0 , minutes: Int
    init(message: String, days:Int ,hours:Int , minutes: Int , seconds: Int ) {
        self.message = message
        self.days = days
        self.hours = hours
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.minutes = minutes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не сделали блок таймера.
Вам следует сделать `Timer` вида:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (_) in
}
```

то есть:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (_) in
   time += 1
   lbl.text = String(time)
   if timer == 5 {
        
       self.present(alert, animated:true)
        
       print("Success")
}
```

Тем более по вашей логике приложения вы не меняете `firstReminder.seconds` чтобы использовать эту переменную.

Что-то типа того будет:

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let firstReminder = Property(message: " ", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 5)
    let secondReminder = Property(message: "Good morning", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 10)
    let thirdReminder = Property(message: "Hi", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 15)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You are playing too much", message: "What about break", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    
    var time = 0
    
    //timer
    var timer = Timer()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupAlertController()
    }
    
    func setupAlertController() {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: {
            (action) in
            print("OK")
        }))
    }
    
    @IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (_) in
            self.action()
        })
    }
    
    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        time = 0
        lbl.text = "0"
    }
    
    @objc func action() {
        time += 1
        lbl.text = String(time)
        
        switch time {
        case firstReminder.seconds:
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        case secondReminder.seconds:
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        case thirdReminder.seconds:
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

public class Property {
    var message: String, days = 0, hours = 1, seconds = 0, minutes: Int
    init(message: String, days: Int, hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
        self.message = message
        self.days = days
        self.hours = hours
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.minutes = minutes
    }
}
```